# How can I achieve this in Windsor Castle? (Migrating from StructureMap)

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I need to modify an existing web app to use Castle.Windsor as IOC container. It was originally developed with StructureMap.

I am stuck with the following problem.

Lets say I have registered a couple of interfaces and their corresponding implementations:

```
IFoo -> Foo
IBar -> Bar
```

Calling `container.Resolve<IFoo>()` or `container.Resolve<IBar>()` works just fine. This means that the services are registered correctly.

I have a Web Api class with dependencies on other services, such as IFoo

```
public class BadRequestErrorHandler : HttpErrorHandler
{
    // services
    public BadRequestErrorHandler(IFoo foo) {...} // has dependency on IFoo
}
```

In StructureMap I can call:

```
var test = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<BadRequestErrorHandler>();
```

this will resolve the IFoo dependency.

Now this does not work with windsor.

How can this be achieved with windsor?

Thanks!

* EDIT ***
I was just able to make it work by explicitely registering the BadRequestErrorHandler.

```
container.Register(Component.For<BadRequestErrorHandler>());
```

I am just hoping there is a better way to achieve this, that does not involve registering classes that have dependencies. I have a bunch of them...

*** EDIT 2 ****

To ease the pain, I added a special method to deal with these concrete types.

```
public T GetInstanceWithAutoRegister<T>()
{
    if (container.Kernel.GetHandler(typeof(T)) == null)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<T>());
    }
    return container.Resolve<T>();
}

public object GetInstanceWithAutoRegister(Type pluginType)
{
    if (container.Kernel.GetHandler(pluginType) == null)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For(pluginType));
    }
    return container.Resolve(pluginType);
}
```

not ideal, but at least better than having to explicetly register each type. Hope someone has a better solution

Comment: Compared to StructureMap, concrete instances cannot be resolved by Castle Windsor, without explicitly registering them. You will need to call `container.Register` on them (per type or by using batch registration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by registering an `ILazyComponentLoader` which is a hook that gets called by Windsor as a "last resort" when a component cannot be resolved.

In your case, the implementation would probably look somewhat like this:

```
public class JustLetWindsorResolveAllConcreteTypes : ILazyComponentLoader
{
    public IRegistration Load(string key, Type service)
    {
        return Component.For(service);
    }
}
```

-and then it should be registered as such:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ILazyComponentLoader>()
         .ImplementedBy<JustLetWindsorResolveAllConcreteTypes>());
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Lazy-Component-Loaders.ashx).

Comment: In addition to what @mookid8000 wrote, also have a look at http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.FAQ.ashx#Why_cant_Windsor_resolve_concrete_types_without_registering_them_first_11 which explains why doing this at all is not a good idea in the first place.